# Asignar fecha por defecto Angular

Tags: html, html5, angular, date, angular8

Buenas tardes estoy manejando un formulario que realiza la modificacion de un usuario,  por lo tanto tengo que rellenarlo con los datos del usuario existentes, mi problema radica en que tengo un input tipo "date" el cual escoge la fecha de nacimiento y a este debo asignarle la fecha que actualmente tiene el usuario pero no me sale, he intentado esto:

```
this.fechanaci = new Date(this.dataUserMod.fechaNacimiento);

<input type="date" class="form-control create-user" value="{{fechanaci}}" (change)="obtenerFecha(fechaNacimiento.value)" id="fechaNacimiento" name="fechaNacimiento"
                          [ngModel]="usuariot.fechaNacimiento"
                          #fechaNacimiento="ngModel">
```

"dataUserMod" es el objeto que tiene los datos del usuario:

```
   dataUserMod:any={
  primerNombre:'Will',
  segundoNombre:'Steve',
  primerApellido:'Ferr',
  segundoApellido:'Duque',
  fechaNacimiento:'5/09/1993',
  codigoUsuario:4,
  sexo:M,
  sucursal:[],
  rol:[],
  telefonoCelular:'09912795599',
  correoElectronico:'will@hotmail.com'
}
```

el valor de "dataUserMod" es obtenido de una api, el campo 'fechaNacimiento' es un string, si el usuario no tiene 'fechaNacimiento' retorna "null"

pero no consigo asignarle la fecha del usuario, agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

Comment: lo que pasa es que la fecha se guarda en long, como mili segundos, lo que debes hacer antes es crear un objeto date algo como: ```dataUserMod.fechaNacimiento = new Date(dataUserMod.fechaNacimiento);```, así se te mostrara en el input

Comment: @Charls edite la pregunta realizando lo que me dijiste pero aun no me sale

Comment: De donde sale **this.dataUserMod.fechaNacimiento**, agrega la función o la parte del **ts** donde lo llenas de valores, ademas cuales son los posibles valores???

Comment: @DavElsanto  ya edite agregando el objeto con los datos del usuario

Comment: ya pero agrega de donde viene o en donde es consultado el valor y es un string??? que pasa cuando no tiene valor esa fecha??? con que valor llega por defecto???

Comment: el valor es obtenido de una api, el campo 'fechaNacimiento' es un string, si el usuario no tiene 'fechaNacimiento' retorna "null"

Answer (score 0):

Para poder asignar una fecha correctamente a un `input:Date` tienes que hacer unos cuantos pasos extras.

```html
<input type='Date' [ngModel]='fecha | date:"yyyy-MM-dd" ' (ngModelChange)='fecha=$event' >
```

---

## Explicacion

Esta linea  `[ngModel]='fecha | date:"yyyy-MM-dd" '` nos permite cargar el valor de manera dinámica en el input.

Esta subseccion `| date:"yyyy-MM-dd"`  es un pipe que transforma el valor de `fecha` antes de asignarlo. Por defecto angular te entrega las fechas con un formato diferente al que se requiere `"yyyy-MM-dd"` De ahí que tengamos que formatear para que el input funcione correctamente.

Después con `(ngModelChange)='fecha=$event'` detectamos cuando el modelo cambia y almacenamos el valor del evento en la variable fecha para tener una versión mas amplia del `[(ngModel)]`

Ejemplo funcional [aquí](https://twobindingwaydate.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 0):

Solo con la información que agregas no es suficiente, sin embargo como mencionas que es un String que al no tener valor su valor es "null" como String, puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
this.fechanaci = this.dataUserMod.fechaNacimiento == 'null' ? new Date() : new Date(this.dataUserMod.fechaNacimiento);
```

Con esto estas diciendo que si la fecha es 'null' toma la fecha de hoy, caso contrario toma la fecha del objeto.

Comment: el api en el campo "fechaNaciemiento" trae un string de esta forma "05/09/1993" cuando es "null" tu respuesta si funciona pero el problema es cuando si trae un valor como  "05/09/1993"

Comment: existe un contructor con string para **new Date()** https://www.javascripture.com/Date